# Enable rangeSelector buttons for asyncLoading without navigator enabled

Tags: highcharts

I need to set my navigator option like the following to allow for async-loading of data (i.e. enable all the rangeSelector buttons):

```
navigator: {
    adaptToUpdatedData: false,
    series : {
        data : seriesData
    }          
},
```

But in fact, I do not want the navigator bar to be displayed but when I do the following:

```
navigator: {
    enabled: false
},
```

the rangeSelector buttons are tuned to the data range and hence some of them get disabled. Any work around for this? I tried setting `height : 0` but it still shows a line with handle buttons.

EDIT:

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwcpb7wm/. Disabling the navigator produces an erratic behavior on the buttons. A quick repro is the following sequence: `1H` - > `1D`

Comment: could you make a JsFiddle that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: You can force enabled buttons by [option](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.allButtonsEnabled), but jsfiddle will be helpful to check the reason of you problem

Comment: I have added a fiddle guys. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related with known bugs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1183 and https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1438.

```
       chart : {
            type: 'candlestick',
            zoomType: 'x',
            events:{
                load:function() {
                this.scroller.handles[0].hide();
                this.scroller.handles[1].hide();
              }
            }
        },

        navigator : {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series : {
                data : data
            },
            height:0,
            xAxis:{
                labels:{
                enabled:false
              }
            },
            yAxis:{
                height:0
            }
        },
```

Workaround is hide SVG elements: http://jsfiddle.net/syu2zcsw/